# Не получается реализовать метод HTTP GET в Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Сервер принимает запросы по получению главной страницы. Однако у меня не получается переходить по ссылкам.

```html
<div id="user">
  <a href="/signUp">Sign up</a>
</div>
```

Метод контроллера:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/signUp",method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String register(){
     return "signup";
 }
```

Настройки:

```
public class SpringMVCDispatcherInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"ru.sfedu"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

У вас в контролеере указан путь - `/signUp` , переходить надо по этому пути, а не по названию метода, вот нужный адрес:

```
localhost:8080/signUp
```

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду это  @RequestMapping(value = "localhost:8080/signUp",method = RequestMethod.GET),то ошибка все еще не решается

Comment: нет, он имеет ввиду что RequestMapping без изменений, а в браузере ввести, то что @user453575457 указал localhost:8080/signUp

Comment: @mish нет, вам не нужны изменения в коде, вам нужен другой адрес в браузере

Comment: Я понял, переделал адрес. Теперь получил ошибку 500. Circular view path [signUp]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/signUp] again. Check your ViewResolver setup!

Comment: У вас путь по которому доступно - указан два раза в value  и в return, в return  - это view  - то есть адрес для фронтенда который надо показывать, а  get value  - это адрес по которому отдает rest get информацию. Ссылась на друг друга бесконечно дают ошибку. Оставьте что-то одно, value  из аннотации get  уберите

Comment: Проблема за проблемой. Теперь у меня в браузере высвечивается не нужная мне страничка , а название представления

Comment: В рамках одного вопроса все приложение мы вам не напишем. Этот вопрос помечайте решенным если помогло, и заадавайте следующий.